# Exporting large PNG images in a java executable compiled with Xcode

Tags: java, heap-memory

I'm trying to export large PNG images from a java .jar executable which I'm building using Xcode 3.1.4.

The basic code looks like:

```
filename = "myImage.png";

bImg = new BufferedImage(7882, 7882, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics2D cg = bImg.createGraphics();

this.repaint(0,0,7882, 7882);
this.paint(cg);
cg.dispose();


ImageIO.write(bImg, "png", new File(filename))l
```

However, since the image is very large I get:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.awt.image.DataBufferInt.<init>(DataBufferInt.java:41)
at java.awt.image.Raster.createPackedRaster(Raster.java:458)
at java.awt.image.DirectColorModel.createCompatibleWritableRaster(DirectColorModel.java:1015)
at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.<init>(BufferedImage.java:315)
```

I know I can increase heap size by using the `-Xmx` flag (for example `-Xmx4g`), and the operation succeeds if I run the .jar file like so:

```
java -Xmx4g -jar myJar.jar
```

However, I'd like to distribute the file such that people can simply double click the .jar file and run it. Hence I need some way to specify the `-Xmx` flag in my Xcode project OR some way of writing the PNG image in stages.

I've tried going into Executables->java->Info->Arguments and add the Argument `-Xmx4g`... It doesn't help. I've tried setting it as a variable too with the name `-Xmx4g`, doesn't help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to specify JVM arguments for an executable JAR per se.

You have few ways to workaround:

1) Ship .cmd and .sh files along with jar to launch java with desired arguments

2) Use a packager/wrapper like [WinRun4j](http://winrun4j.sourceforge.net/), [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) and so on

3) Ship jar as before. In main() check JVM arguments, if not launched with desired memory argument, determine path of your jar and launch with [Runtime.exec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)) a new java jar process with desired memory argument.

Comment: well, none of those sounds especially aesthetic... but I guess I'll go with #2

Comment: I think this is the best path if you can afford the time to investigate and maintain it. We wrap our Windows products with WinRun4j in automatic builds and are quite satisfied. It took some time to figure out configuration and all corners, though.